# ImageMagick convert always modifies my jpg

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I wanted to use convert to modify just the exif orientation tag of a jpg file:

```
convert original.jpg -set Exif:Orientation 1 new.jpg
```

I expected new.jpg to differ from orignal.jpg only in a few bytes. But actually the new file is 10k smaller than the original and its color statistics have changed slightly. This happens even if I don't specify any operation at all:

```
convert original.jpg new.jpg
```

Here I would expect new.jpg to be identical to original.jpg except possibly for some modification date but certainly there shouldn't be any difference in the image data, right?
I can keep running convert (or mogrify) without operation on the new file and it will keep producing new files that all have different statistics (but look equal to the human eye).

Comment: Perhaps a different utlility would be better to use for this, e.g. [Exifer](http://www.friedemann-schmidt.com/software/exifer/). I couldn't find an option in ImageMagick to leave the image data alone, although that does not mean there is not such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have more luck with `jhead`, available from [here](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/).

It has two options that might be useful to you:

```
-autorot   Set rotation automatically
-norot     Clear rotation flag (maybe add `-rgt` to regenerate thumbnail)
```

Alternatively, you may get on better with `exiftool`, available [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html) .

Use it like this:

```
exiftool -Orientation=1 -n SomeImage.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you recompress a JPEG image using the exact same compression settings you will get some change in the image. Even if you use the exact settings you may get changes due to rounding errors.

The settings that need to be the same are the quantization tables and sampling rates.

Comment: so if I understand correctly convert/mogrify decompresses the image on input and compresses it newly on output even if no pixel is modified. every time it does so it creates different data due to rounding errors (every new file has different statistics). in my example this happened 34 times in a row until the process converged to a constant file. So maybe @Andrew Morton is right in saying that a different tool would be appropriate.